# Trying to send query to Google using javascript's window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send a query to Google using javascript, but the window just goes to the home-page.

Here is my code:

```
var query = "hello world";
var firstPart = "http://google.com/?=";
window.location.href = firstPart + query;
```

The URl of the page is correct, but it doesn't go to the results.

Comment: where is the q? Add the `?q=` to the querystring. Marked to close since it is a typo.

Comment: oops, looks like I forgot it. I sincerely apologise for the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
var firstPart = "http://google.com/?=";
```

To:

```
var firstPart = "http://google.com/search?q=";
```

Use their [Search Protocol](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/62/xml_reference):

https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/62/xml_reference

Comment: Thank you. I apologise for it being a typo.